# Call an object like it's a function?

Tags: php, function, class

Is there any way in PHP to call an object like it's a function?

```
class Funct {
  public function __callSelf() {
    echo 'Called!';
  }
}

$myFunc = new Funct();
$myFunc();

// Output

Called!
```

Something like this?

Comment: What'll you achieve from this? Care to explain?

Comment: @PankajSharma, nothing special, just trying something fun, making my code more concise probably, such as from $obj -> makeDo() to $obj(), but this may not be a good idea as it seems to reduce code readability.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can try with [`__invoke`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#object.invoke) magic method.

> The __invoke() method is called when a script tries to call an object as a function.
>
> *Note:*
> This feature is available since PHP 5.3.0.

Comment: Would it be possible to call a function within the `__construct` method of a class for pre PHP 5.3.0 versions?

Comment: @KhorneHoly - The __construct() method of a class doesn't stop you calling functions even in versions of PHP prior to 5.3.0, so I don't understand what you mean

Comment: @MarkBaker What i meant was if it is possible to do something like `__construct(){ $this->function() }` as workaround for PHP versions pre 5.3 :) Sorry for the missunderstandig, hope it's clear now

Comment: @KhorneHoly - that wouldn't achieve the same objective at all; it would simply call a method called `function()` on instantiation

Answer (score -1):

Try with `__construct()` or `__invoke()`.